# Compass in Windows Phone 8.1 COMException OnPropertyChanged MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, compass

I got a problem with my MVVM pattern.

```
class MagnetometrViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Compass compass;
    double temp;
    public MagnetometrViewModel()
    {
        compass = Compass.GetDefault();
        CompassControl_Loaded();
    }

    private double heading;
    public double Heading
    {
        get
        {
            return heading;
        }
        set
        {
            heading = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Heading");
        }
    }

    private void CompassControl_Loaded()
    {
        compass = Windows.Devices.Sensors.Compass.GetDefault();
        if (compass != null)
        {
            compass.ReadingChanged += CompassReadingChanged;
        }
    }

    private void CompassReadingChanged(Windows.Devices.Sensors.Compass sender, Windows.Devices.Sensors.CompassReadingChangedEventArgs args)
    {

         temp = Convert.ToDouble(args.Reading.HeadingMagneticNorth);
         Heading = temp;
         //Heading = Convert.ToDouble(args.Reading.HeadingMagneticNorth);
    }

    #region PropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

When I debuging on that line 
    temp = Convert.ToDouble(args.Reading.HeadingMagneticNorth);
it get the result, but my other method OnPropertyChanged throws exception: 
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Comment: Is this in a Silverlight, or Universal app?

Comment: You are getting a COMException on windows phone, I am not sure how that is even possible?

Comment: It's a Windows Phone application for Windows Store

Comment: Never.  Never.  Ever.  Ask about an exception and not include the full exception details.  There's a link on the exception helper dialog to copy the exception details to the clipboard.  Or you call ToString on the exception object instance and add that to your question.  Without full details, you're lucky (as here) to get an answer.

Comment: Ok, I remember it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fire the `PropertyChanged` events on the UI thread, if you're doing a Silverlight Windows Phone app, then you can do something a little like:

```
    protected delegate void OnUIThreadDelegate();
    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the specified delegate to be performed on the UI thread.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="onUIThreadDelegate">The delegate to be executed on the UI thread.</param>
    protected static void OnUIThread(OnUIThreadDelegate onUIThreadDelegate)
    {
        if (onUIThreadDelegate != null)
        {
            if (Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                onUIThreadDelegate();
            }
            else
            {
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(onUIThreadDelegate);
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        OnUIThread(() =>
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        });
    }
```

If you're using the more modern Universal style apps, then simply change the `OnUIThread` implementation to be something more like:

```
    protected async void OnUIThread(DispatchedHandler onUIThreadDelegate)
    {
        if (onUIThreadDelegate != null)
        {
            var dispatcher = CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher;
            if (dispatcher.HasThreadAccess)
            {
                onUIThreadDelegate();
            }
            else
            {
                await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, onUIThreadDelegate);
            }
        }
    }
```